# Can't use "Generate Random String" keyword on Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, robotframework

I'm new with RobotFramework. I want to use the "Generate Random String" keyword but the system doesn't recognize it as a valid one, although I'm importing the String Library. Maybe is outdated? How can I update a "built-in" library in Robot Framework?

I'm using Python 2.7.10 with Pycharm CE

Sorry if I don't provide all the info needed, is my first question here.

Comment: Please show your actual code, and the error or log message that says it isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

What does your current test look like? [`Generate Random String`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Generate%20Random%20String) is part of the String library. While it is included when you install RobotFramework, you have to explicitly import the Library in the Settings section.

```
***Settings***
Library    String
```

Keyword: `Generate Random String    length=8    chars=[LETTERS][NUMBERS]`

Example usage from the documentation:

```
${ret} =    Generate Random String      
${low} =    Generate Random String    12    [LOWER]
${bin} =    Generate Random String    8     01
${hex} =    Generate Random String    4     [NUMBERS]abcdef
```

*Edit:* Full example test:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    String

*** Test Cases ***
Random Stuff
    ${ret}=    Generate Random String
    ${low}=    Generate Random String    12    [LOWER]
    ${bin}=    Generate Random String    8     01
    ${hex}=    Generate Random String    4     [NUMBERS]abcdef
```

The logs show the random values it gets: xcc3XUjZ, iuuvcqxvamam, 01000000, 4ce2. Without posting the script you're using and some of the error, we can't help further.

Comment: thanks for your quick response, yes. I'm declaring the library String under Settings section and then I try to use the keyword, but is not recognized. The most disturbing part is that the library string is actually imported and recognized by robotframework.

Comment: Are you getting some other import errors? I've updated the answer with the example from the docs.  Without posting the script you're using and some of the error, we can't help further.

Comment: I'm not getting any error, "Generate Random String" keyword appears with a red underline and the warning "Keyword definition not found". String library is properly configured under the Settings section.

Comment: `*** Settings ***

Library  String


*** Test Cases ***

${ret}=  Generate Random String`

Comment: Have you tried running the test? Maybe its just an issue with the plugin for PyCharm.

Comment: @LeonardoQAC Based on what you pasted above, your test case doesn't have a name, or you've forgotten to give it one and RF considers `${ret}= Generate Random String` as your attempt to give it that name. Syntax error.